# Storing Lua callback functions

Tags: c++, lua

I have a game I am integrating with Lua scripting in order to allow customization.

I am using a C++ Lua wrapper:
https://github.com/tomaka/luawrapper

In my Lua script I am calling something like this:

```
function sprite_factory()
  local sprite = sprite_new() -- register_new_sprite(name)
  sprite:RegisterCallback("on_activate", function ()
    sprite:SetState("closed")
  end)
end
```

In my C++ code I have built a Sprite class and I'm using `registerFunction` to make the member methods available to Lua e.g. `RegisterCallback` is called on the sprite object returned by `sprite_new()`

```
bool RegisterCallback(const std::string hook, const std::function<void()> callback) {
    callback();
    mCallback = callback;
    return true;
}
```

If I do the callback inside the `RegisterCallback` method, it works fine. However, I want to store the callback to be used as a raised event.

When I call this method later in my code:

```
void DoCallback() {
    mCallback(); //raises exception
}
```

I get an exception:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   std::__1::bad_function_call: std::exception

I am declaring mCallback as a private:

```
std::function<void()> mCallback = NULL;
```

I'm not sure what is going on here.

Comment: As a follow up I inspected the state in debugger and mCallback shows a private member of __f_ set to a function, however later in the program when DoCallback is called, __f_ is set to nil.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that there is an issue with the way mCallback is declared.